# how to find global minimum and max over set s

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, global-optimization

I need to find the global minimum and maximum points of the linear function
 $f (x, y) = 5x − 8y$ over the
set $S =\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2: 5x^2 − 8xy + 4y^2 + 8x − 8y ≤ 5\}$

Comment: Differentiate directly and use Lagrange multiplier method

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: thank you I know that method but I have to solve it without lagrange multiplier

Comment: Well, since the function is linear, the maxima are surely found at the edge of the region. So consider
$$
5x^2 -8xy + 4y^2 + 8x -8y = 5
$$
which is an ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, your problem is convex:

$$\text{min./max. }f(x,y) = 5x - 8y$$

$$\text{s.t. }  5x^2 - 8xy + 4y^2 + 8x-8y \leq 5$$

You can see that the inequality constraint could be written as $(x~y)^T = z$ and $z^T A z + c^T z \leq 5$, which might be the more intuitive equation to see it's an ellipse (see the [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5x%5E2%E2%88%928xy%2B4y%5E2%2B8x%E2%88%928y%3D5)).

Affine functions (as your objective) are convex, any set $S$ bound by an ellipse is a convex set

$$S = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n| x^T A x + c^T x \leq b\}$$

For convex problems [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) holds, there exists one unique solution (the global maximum/minimum), hence you are searching for each *one* minimum and maximum. As @Matti P. has already mentioned, it will be on the edge of the ellipse, which means

$$5x^2 - 8xy + 4y^2 + 8x-8y = 5$$

Solving this equation and plugging it into the now un-constrained problem, I come up with:

$$(x, y)_{min} = \left(\frac{9}{5}, 4 \right)$$

$$(x, y)_{max} = \left(-\frac{9}{5}, -2  \right)$$

with $f((x, y)_{min}) = -23$ and $f((x, y)_{max}) = 7$, which looks rougly looks like this [solution plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%285x%5E2%20-%208xy%20%2B%204y%5E2%20%2B%208x-8y%20%3D%205%2C%205x-8y%3D-23%2C%205x-8y%3D7%29). I hope this helps.

Comment: Also, $\nabla(5x^2 - 8xy + 4y^2 + 8x-8y) =  \nabla (5x-8y)$, but it is Lagrangian-esque, which you wouldn't want to use.